# Unable to change color of UISearchDisplayController

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm using `UISearchDisplayController`on `UInavigationBar` but the background color of `UISearchDisplayController` is not matching the color of uinavigationbar. i used the following code in ma `ViewDidLoad` but no change I'm unable to change the color of `UISearchDisplayController`

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did was I created a `UISearchBar` subclass and in IB made the searchBar belonging to the  `UISearchDisplayController` part of that subclass. From there I was able to change the `tintColor` and `backgroundColor`. The reason I needed this was because the `UISearchBar` was not displaying correctly within a `UINavigationBar` and this was the only way I could think of on, how to do it.

**Edit**

Your actually able to do this relatively easy with `UISearchDisplayController`'s initializer, `initWithSearchBar:contentsController:`, however you'll still need to subclass `UISearchBar`.

---

Here is the Code I used. Now if your performing this through IB you only need to use `initWithCoder:` but I created a `setup` method. Just incase, I need to use it again, in places other than IB.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) setup {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    for (UIView * view in self.subviews) {
        if ([view isMemberOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) {
            view.alpha = 0.0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `UISearchDisplayController` is not an interface element. It is a controller, not a view. It has no color.

Comment: I think he understands that but `UISearchDisplayController` has a `searchBar` property. Which he is using in his code example.